# Entire nav bar disappearing after jQuery click function in responsive site

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, nav

I'm making a responsive site that has a collapsible nav bar when viewing on small screens only.

The problem I'm having is that it is disappearing when I adjust the screen larger after I have clicked the menu on and off. This would only affect a very tiny amount of people who might resize their browsers often and click the menu.

There must be something logically that I'm missing, but can't figure it out.

HTML:

```
    <nav id="mainNav">
        <img id="menu" src="menu.png" alt="menu icon" width="50" />
        <ul id="slide">
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#calendar">Calendar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sponsors">Sponsors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#mainNav {
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 500;
}

#menu {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    #menu {
        display: block;
    }

    #slide {
        display: none;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    "use strict";

        $("#menu").click(function(){ 
            if ($("#slide").css("display") === "block") {
                $("#slide").css({ "display": "none" });
            }
            else if($("#slide").css("display") === "none") {
                $("#slide").css({ "display": "block" });
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: the jquery css function overrides the css style

Comment: Is there a way I can reverse it when the screen is made larger again?

Comment: only with javascript

Comment: Could you be more specific? I'm willing to use JavaScript for the entire function if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter the script like this:

```
     $(function () {
  $("#menu").click(function () {
    if ($("#slide").is(':hidden')) {
      $("#slide").show();
    } else {
      $("#slide").hide();
    }
  });
  $(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 500) {
      $("#slide").show();
    } else {
      $("#slide").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

see jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b7v14zkf/